# What is BMK Operator in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, operator

I was trying to answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586365/sql-update-statement-with-different-table-in-from-clause) stating from clause is optional..But i am stuck with an Operator in plan..below is screenshot of execution plan ..

[image]

As you can see there is BMK operator in query plan ,but no indication showing how it is calculated..

**steps i have tried so far:**
I started searching with BMK1000 ,but it shows a bunch of questions with the same operator.finally i found one [thread](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1683132-391-1.aspx) which says "The BMK that you're referencing is the storage location within the heap that gets kept with the nonclustered index instead of the cluster key."..But not sure how this is related to me,since i don't have any indexes..

**ASK:**
what is the BMK operator and how it is calculated.Any Pointers also will be helpfull

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/517093/bmk?opt.withExecutionPlan=true#executionPlan) to Repro the issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not an [operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191158.aspx) in its own right. It is an output column from the table scan operator on the heap. It is the "bookmark" that contains the physical address of the row (this is the same bookmark as is referred to in the phrase "bookmark lookup").

This is passed along the pipeline into the update operator so it knows the row it should be updating.

In SQL Server 2016 you can see the actual values for this column by using the [`query_trace_column_values`](http://www.queryprocessor.com/query-trace-column-values/) extended event

[image]

Plugging those into `sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter` shows the `file:page:slot`

```
SELECT sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(0xB002000001), 
       sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(0xB0020000010001)
```

Returns

```
+------------------+------------------+
| (No column name) | (No column name) |
+------------------+------------------+
| (1:688:0)        | (1:688:1)        |
+------------------+------------------+
```